# How to use multiple DataTables retured from one stored procedure in another stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dataset

I have a stored procedure "Old" returning 3 tables where the first two tables return a single row of XML type, and the third table returns 'n' rows of date type.

Now, I am executing the "Old" stored procedure in a "New" stored procedure and want to store the 3 result set values returned by it in "New" stored procedure.

**Old SP:**

```
Select * from Table1 
Select * from Table2
Select * from Table3
```

**New SP :**

```
EXEC Old
```

Also, I don't want to merge these 3 tables into one in "Old" stored procedure and then return it to "New" stored procedure.

Comment: T-SQL itself doesn't have any means to handle multiple result sets from a stored procedure, surprinsingly. The only way I know of is to use C# with ADO.NET - the ADO.NET `SqlCommand` can return and properly handle multiple result sets

Comment: You could create #temp tables in your New proc which the Old proc could access and insert the results into, then you would have the data available.

Comment: As mentioned by @marc_s you're probably better off doing this with code layer (C# or any other). You also have the following options (*though these are not the best way to go about*) 1. Create a new "Old" SP which merges them (*replace this "Old" SP*). 2. Pass an additional param to "Old" based on which either table 1, 2, 3 or all is/are returned.

Comment: I'd suggest you just copy-paste the code from `OldSP`